# What is the correct pattern for pgbadger to match RDS logs?

Tags: regex, postgresql, rds, pgbadger

I am trying to parse the log file generated by my RDS instance using `pgBadger`, so far with no results.

The log_line_prefix is set to `%t:%r:%u@%d:[%p]:`

A sample line in the log file looks like :

```
2019-09-24 17:19:25 UTC:172.31.10.173(53224):username@database:[12829]:LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1
```

I am using pgbadger with this command:

```
./pgbadger -p "%t:%r:%u@%d:[%p]:" postgresql.log.2019-09-24-17 -o pgbadger_rdsinstance.html
```

It throws the below error

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(?:\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+Z)?\s*(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s*[^:]*:( <-- HERE [^\(:]+\(\d+\):([^\@]+)\@([^:]+):\[(\d+)\]:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?: [A-Z\+\-\d]{3,6})?:([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+|\[local\]|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[0-9a-fA-F:]+)?[\(\d\)]*:([0-9a-zA-Z\_\[\]\-\.]*)@([0-9a-zA-Z\_\[\]\-\.]*):\[(\d+)\]:(LOG|WARNING|ERROR|FATAL|PANIC|DETAIL|STATEMENT|HINT|CONTEXT|LOCATION):\s+(.*)/ at ./pgbadger line 2430.
```

Not sure what should be the correct pattern here. Looks like it isnt able to parse `172.31.10.173(53224)`.

I tried by escaping the parenthesis like : `%t:%r\\(%a\\):%u@%d:[%p]:`, but that doesnt help.

I parsed a sample log file by removing this `(53224)` part, and it works just fine.

What should be the correct pattern for this prefix?

Comment: I just removed the ports from the log file using `sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'` and I am able to use pgbadger now. Works for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is pgBadger 11.1 or newer, you can try using `--format rds` and remove `--prefix`.  I guess this is a new bug that needs to be reported, but at least `--format rds` worked for me.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/issues/536